# Generate sets of numbers which only have a difference of 1 from the last set of numbers in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, random, 2d

Problem: I want to generate random locations on a grid which are touching. The total number of locations is 5. Is there a more efficient/different way of doing the following code:

```
 /*
 * 8        1       2
 * 7    [original]  3
 * 6        5       4
 */


int rand = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((8 - 1) + 1));
if(rand >= 2 && rand<= 4)
{
    newx++;
}
else if(rand >=6 && rand<=8)
{
    newx--;
}

//change y according to number
if(rand == 8 || rand == 1 || rand==2)
{
    newy++;
}
else if(rand >= 4 && rand<= 6 )
{
    newy--;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "touching"? Could you give a sample output?

Comment: do you use the "rank" variable after that? or it's only for picking a random int [1,8]? Could you post the whole method?

Comment: @tunaki choose a location as specified (like 1-8) at random and then use the location specified to generate another location

Comment: @Konstantinos Chalkias the rest of the code simply maps out the drawn shape in a jframe for the user to see. It's part of a game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise on the use of `Random.nextInt(8)` Vs `Math.random()*8` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint) why). Because your current requirements seem to allow one "seed" only, you could declare a `static Random random = new Random();` in your class, so you just call `random.nextInt(8)` in your method.

```
int rand = random.nextInt(8); //0..7
if (rand < 3) //0,1,2
{
    newx++;
}
else if (rand < 6) //3,4,5
{
    newx--;
}

//change y according to number
if(rand % 3 == 0) //0,3,6
{
    newy++;
}
else if(rand % 3 == 1) //1,4,7
{
    newy--;
}
```

As you may notice, the above has the same impact with your approach, but uses the modulo operation mainly for readability purposes, cause *mod* is [not as fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141802/efficient-modulo-3-operation) as an `if` checking.

Small Edit by OP: (result of random represented graphically on x and y axis)

```
  6         3       0
  5      [origin]   2
  4         7       1
```

Comment: I'm amazed into the effort that went into this. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086529/what-is-the-relative-performance-difference-of-if-else-versus-switch-statement-i) a `switch` statement seems to be more efficient for your case. Also it makes your code way more readable.

```
switch (rand){
    case 1:         newy++; break;
    case 2: newx++; newy++; break;
    case 3: newx++;         break;
    case 4: newx++; newy--; break;
    case 5:         newy--; break;
    case 6: newx--; newy--; break;
    case 7: newx--;         break;
    case 8: newx--; newy++; break;
}
```